# How to merge the result of two queries using update

Tags: python, django

I have to show the name of the category and the quantity of items in each category.
The items can change the category, so I save the history of the items in the table `items_history`

To show all the category name I'm running this query:

```
category_total = Category.objects.all()
```

Example of result:

`<QuerySet [<Category: Drink>, <Category: Food>, <Category: Fun>, <Category: Suplies>]>`

To get the quantity of items in each category, I have to check in the table `items_history`:

```
items_history = Category.objects.filter(items_history__current=1).annotate(qtd=Count("items_history__idea_id"))
```

Example of result:

```
<QuerySet [<Category: Food>]> 
 items_history[0].name -> 'Food'
 items_history[0].qtd -> 5
```

In this case, I have only items in Food Category. So I can't do just one query in `items_history`, because I'm not gonna get the quantity of the items in the other categories (0, in this case).

I need to get all the categories with their respective quantity, so if a category is not persisted in `items_history` I should get the category `name` and the `quantity = 0`. 
The result expected:

```
        items_history[0].name -> 'Drink'
        items_history[0].qtd -> 0

        items_history[1].name -> 'Food'
        items_history[1].qtd -> 5

        items_history[1].name -> 'Fun'
        items_history[1].qtd -> 0

        items_history[1].name -> 'Suplies'
        items_history[1].qtd -> 0
```

I'm trying to use `update` to merge the result of `category_total` and `items_history` like this:

```
 category_total.update(items_history);
```

But it's not working. How can I do that? If it's not possible, do u have other idea to merge the results of those queries?

My model:

```
 class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True,  null=True)
        order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=False)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name



    class Items_History(models.Model):  # noqa   
        current_phase = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        previous_phase = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
        date_change = models.DateTimeField('data da mudança')
        idea = models.ForeignKey('Idea', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        author = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        current = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: django version:  2.0.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), we can use a `filter` parameter in the [**`Count`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#aggregation-functions).

This thus allows us to write a query like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Category.objects.annotate(
    qtd=Count("items_history__idea_id", filter=Q(items_history__current=1))
)
```

This will thus shift the filtering to is done in the `COUNT(..)` part itself, like:

```
SELECT category.*, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN items_history.current
                THEN items_history.idea_id
                ELSE NULL END) AS qtd
FROM category
LEFT OUTER JOIN items_history ON category.id = items_history.current_phase_id
GROUP BY category.id
```

In case for the *same* `Item` and the *same* `Category`, there can be multiple `Item_History`s with `current` is set to `True`, you also might want to add the `distinct=True` flag to it:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

Category.objects.annotate(
    qtd=Count(
        "items_history__idea_id",
        filter=Q(items_history__current=1),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Comment: Awesome. Tku so much. That's a really elegant way to solve it.